# how to handle a user with old vue code in memory and new release out?

Tags: vue.js

Anyone got a way they handle this..

1 you build and release the frontend to prod

2 users visit the site and use the app

3 you build and release to prod a bug fix to page A, the built chunks that were affected from the new code now have a new file hash (from webpack)

4 the user is still on your site, so no need to refresh, but clicks a link to page A, but hadn't previously been to page A. Now the app throws an error as it tries to fetch a link that requires
a chunk that doesn't exist anymore..

I'm configuring the pwa setup so the app will know when a new update is available... But it feels like this scenario will not be completely fixed with a pwa manifest alone. Also new to the pwa stuff.

Another idea i was toying with was to make use of the apps socket connections and push a message to all apps to refresh.. but this feels overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you check the Service Worker registrations. It sounds to me like this might be the issue.

Comment: Also got sent this related post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601121/code-splitting-causes-chunks-to-fail-to-load-after-new-deployment-for-spa